# wss 3.0 workflow approval close task

Tags: workflow, task, wss

We have a customized worklfow for one stage approve/reject only in wss 3.0 sP2 which is working fine. The only issue is the one described below:

Approve is getting notification via email when task is assigned to them. Approver can approve/reject task using that link in email. However, if approver open that link again, he can still do the same thing.

Is there any way we can say to approver that you have already closed this task when he opens link again?